# Magento 2 - bundle product

Tags: magento2, product, stock, bundled-product

I want to sell in Magento 2 products that depend from production. I will explain this base on coffee.

Let say I have 1 Kg of seeds arabika as a simple product. This translate to 900 g of ground arabika.

I also have 1 Kg of seeds robusta as a simple product. This translate to 900g of ground robusta.

That I can achieve with bundle product. But now I have a mix of this two as mix.
900g ground arabika and 900g robusta translate to 1 mix of coffee.

Can I cherate that kinda chain? 
I mention that I can have in stock 10 Kg arabika and robusta, 900 g ground arabika and robusta and 2 mix as a final boxed product.